# Hosting Web API in .Net Core Worker Service - cannot reference IWebHostEnvironment

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm creating a .NET Core Worker Service, and want to expose ASP.Net Core Web APIs for the service. I'm using .NET Core 3.0. 
Initially, my plan was to replace IHostBuilder with IWebHostBuilder and add a Startup class just like a regular Asp.Net Core web app (this is probably an oversimplification, though).

My plan was to simply try to replace

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)                
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
        }
```

with

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                }).UseStartup<Startup>();            
        }
```

which may not work at all, but at least it's a starting point...
What's blocking me from trying this approach is that I cannot implement my `Startup` class because `IWebHostEnvironment` is unavailable.

Here's my

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-WorkerServices-0E977A2C-F0C8-49E7-B00A-5EB01B99FBEB</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

As far as I know, `IWebHostEnvironment` should be in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` nuget package, but referencing it does not seem to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?
-Thanks!

Comment: If you are targeting dotnet core 3.0, you should remove ```<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />``` and ```<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />``` lines completely. Recommended reading [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is much easier to add a service to an API project. That's just one extra line.

If you can't or don't want to start over, change your project manually. Forget about `IWebHostBuilder`, it is now obsolete or deprecated or something.

I could post some fragments here but much easier: create a temporary API project, copy over the Program and Startup classes (but keep your namespaces) and then, inside Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();  // the worker will run
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! However, it still bugs me that adding web api support _to_ a project created using the _Worker Service_ template is non-trivial because of what seems to be a nuget / package version issue (or something else that I don't understand). Any suggestions to docs I can read that can explain why adding a nuget package (seemingly) containing the correct types and methods, still won't let me use those APIs?

Comment: May also be done by just editing the csproj file of the worker_service template by this: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

Comment: This doesn't work. Yes, the service runs in the background, after the WebAPI is started. The worker service doesn't start on it's own. That apparently is only possible with a pure "Worker Service" template.

Comment: this is a masterpeace! One Question left: It's working only with localhost. Where do I tell the service the URL to bind on, thus its a win service and normally this would be done on IIS side? I need to bind it to the IP adress of the deployed server

Answer (score 9):

I researched a lot and I did this issue using some new methods which were not well-formed and lack performance, and I tried to find a correct way of doing this problem, finally, I solved it and I've shared my experiences in this post. You can use the following steps which are working 100%, and also, you can clone the Worker-Service Web-API template from my GitHub profile.

Actually, you needn't use IWebHostBuilder. The following steps are enough to self-host a WebAPI in a .net core worker service and host worker service in windows services:

1. Create a simple console application.
2. Install packages "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" using NuGet in your console application.
3. Create an empty file named Worker.cs and put the following code inside it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WorkerServiceWebAppTemplate
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above class is your worker service main file which is inherited from BackgroundService, personally, I inherit IHostedService most of the time.

4. Create another file named Startup.cs and put the following lines of codes:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WorkerServiceWebAppTemplate
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            else
                app.UseHsts();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The Startup file is your web server file and it starts a host and has a simple GET API (/) returns a simple message, you can extend it.

5. Finally, you've to start your worker service and your host at the same time. change your Program.cs like the following codes:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WorkerServiceWebAppTemplate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

The following lines in your Program.cs file do the magic:

```cs
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Comment: in net5.0 UseWindowsService() is no longer a method in IHostBuilder. Any other ideas?

Comment: Install "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" package from NuGet, then update all your existing packages as well. so you can use UseWindowsService() method.

Comment: dotnet add PROJECT_NAME package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices

Comment: I'm using this and it works, but how would you hook this up with controllers? When i add MapControllers in the app.UseEndpoints and call AddControllers inside ConfigureServices, it cant find the controller. I copied over the dummy WeatherForecastController from the sample rest api but it's not finding it

Comment: This is great. Do you have an update for .NET 6?

Comment: .Net 6 doesn't allow the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to be added

Answer (score 2):

Some excellent answers here, but in the fast moving world of .NET services, this has changed again with .NET Core 6+ so...

Despite what it says at the top of this otherwise very useful [Microsoft web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), you're best off creating a Web API, as @H H says, and then adding the Windows service.

So this line in Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Must become:

```
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService()
        ? AppContext.BaseDirectory
        : default
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);
```

Then create a dummy Worker Service app, and copy the Worker.cs file to the Web API project. It is from this Worker class that you can spin up whatever API you want.

The final change you need to make to the Web API `Program.cs` file is to tell it to add a worker service, and then present itself as Windows service:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
```